# Assign Data.Now to HTML.TextBoxFor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am having a problem saving a date in MVC/EF. I have a checkbox and a textbox. I check the checkbox and jq assigns the current date to the textbox.  When the form is submitted though the model shows this data as 01-01-0001.  Besides being the wrong date it also throws a DateTime2 error.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.OK, new { id = "cbOk"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.OkDate, new { id = "OkDate", @readonly = true})
```

jquery

```
$('#cbOk').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#OkDate').val(new Date(Date.now()));
    }
})
```

in the model

```
    [Display(Name = "OK Date"), 
    DataType(DataType.DateTime),
    DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime OkDate { get; set; }
```

What would be the correct way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: You should not be posting back that value (just display it in a (say) `<div>` element. The value of that property should be set in the POST method immediately before you save the record to the db.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - not sure I follow.  When I assign the value to the textbox it becomes part of the model which is then posted back to the controller.  Are you saying it shouldn't be added to the model?

Comment: No I'm saying that it should not be set in the client using javascript. It should be set in the controller method when you save.

Comment: ok I see.  just show the date up front but assign and save it in the controller.. that would work - good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for getting the date on MM/dd/yyyy format

```
    var today = new Date();
    var t_month = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var t_day = today.getDate();

    $("#OkDate").val(t_month + '/' + t_day + '/' + today.getFullYear());
```

Comment: Sure seems like a round about way to get there .. but it worked! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Textbox needs to receive a string.

```
$('#OkDate').val(new Date(Date.now()));
```

This is inserting a Date object to the TextBox.
Try converting to string:

```
  $('#OkDate').val(new Date(Date.now()).toString());
```

Comment: I have tried :          $('#OkDate').val(new Date("2018-01-29").toString());
and  $('#OkDate').val(new Date(Date,now()).toString('2018-01-29'))' but the value sent to the textbox is Mon Jan 29 2018 20:48:01 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) --- when submitted it is converted to 01-01-0001